# IBM J9 View nursery and tenure areas using JMX

Tags: garbage-collection, jmx

I'm searching for a possibility to view using JMX (eg. jConsole) the tenure and nursery areas in IBM J9 JVM?
I connected to IBM Websphere instance (which is using gencon GC - I checked it in logs by using verbose GC) and I can see few Memory Pools:

- Memory Pool "Java heap"
- Memory Pool "JIT code cache"
- Memory Pool "class storage"
- Memory Pool "JIT data cache"
- Memory Pool "miscellaneous non-heap storage"

Unfortunatelly I can't find any way to view the tenured and nursery areas.

I checked in Hotspot and there are explicite memory areas for Eden, Survivor and Old generations.

Is there a way to view those areas in J9 JVM using JMX?

Details about my JVM:

> Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build pxa6460_26sr8ifix-20140630_01(SR8+IX90144+IV62044))
>   IBM J9 VM (build 2.6, JRE 1.6.0 Linux amd64-64 Compressed References 20140409_195736 (JIT enabled, AOT enabled)
>
> J9VM - R26_Java626_SR8_20140409_1526_B195736
>
> JIT  - r11.b06_20140409_61252
>
> GC   - R26_Java626_SR8_20140409_1526_B195736_CMPRSS
>
> J9CL - 20140409_195736)
>
> JCL  - 20140406_01

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no way to get the tenure and nursery areas in IBM J9 JVM.

However IBM provide some consumability tools for parsing verbosegc files (and many other tools too!)

https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/jdk/tools/gcmv/

You can load a verbose GC file into this and view either the raw data, structured data or line plots.

In the verbosegc file incidently, the tenured and nursery stats begin with tags such as :

```
<mem type="nursery"

<mem type="tenured"
```

Comment: Good point, maybe I'll consider some automatic parsing of verbosegc stats. For now, we already have some monitoring tools that are based on JMX stats available in Websphere Application Server and we're looking for a way to view some more verbose gc stats (nursery/tenured areas) this way...